# Parameter details of OpenSSL's AES_ctr128_encrypt()

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, libcrypto

I am trying to understand the parameters of the following function in openSSL crypto library.

```
void AES_ctr128_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
    size_t length, const AES_KEY *key,
    unsigned char ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE],
    unsigned char ecount_buf[AES_BLOCK_SIZE],
    unsigned int *num);
```

By working through the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141860/aes-ctr-256-encryption-mode-of-operation-on-openssl) I was able to figure out:

```
*in - is the buffer in.
*out - is the buffer out.
length - is the the length of the *in buffer.
*key - is the private key.
ivec[0-7] - is the random IV
ivec[8-15] - is the counter thats incremented for every block that's encrypted.
```

> I am not certain about the `ecount_buf` and `num` parameters.

I see that `num` is set to `length % AES_BLOCK_SIZE` after the call returns.

> Any pointers to what the `ecount_buf` parameter is for ?

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation code taken from [here](http://opensource.apple.com//source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-22/openssl/crypto/aes/aes_ctr.c):

```
/* The input encrypted as though 128bit counter mode is being
 * used.  The extra state information to record how much of the
 * 128bit block we have used is contained in *num, and the
 * encrypted counter is kept in ecount_buf.  Both *num and
 * ecount_buf must be initialised with zeros before the first
 * call to AES_ctr128_encrypt().
 */
void AES_ctr128_encrypt(const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
    const unsigned long length, const AES_KEY *key,
    unsigned char counter[AES_BLOCK_SIZE],
    unsigned char ecount_buf[AES_BLOCK_SIZE],
    unsigned int *num) {

    unsigned int n;
    unsigned long l=length;

    assert(in && out && key && counter && num);
    assert(*num < AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    n = *num;

    while (l--) {
        if (n == 0) {
            AES_encrypt(counter, ecount_buf, key);
            AES_ctr128_inc(counter);
        }
        *(out++) = *(in++) ^ ecount_buf[n];
        n = (n+1) % AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    *num=n;
}
```

you can deduce that it is an intermediate buffer for holding the **e**ncrypted **count**er. `num` holds the state information (in case of subsequent calls that we might make in order to chain extra data) in a form of the number of bytes used out of the total block size.